# Building Kurento on lubuntu 15.04

Tags: cmake, fiware, kurento

I am trying to build whole Kurento on my lubuntu 15.04 (same as ubuntu 15.04 vivid with different UI). I started by cloning all repos:

```
mkdir kurento
cd kurento

git clone  https://github.com/Kurento/kms-jsonrpc.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-module-creator.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-core.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-elements.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/adm-scripts.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-cmake-utils.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-crowddetector.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-pointerdetector.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-platedetector.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-plugin-sample.git
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample.git
```

then installing kms-cmake-utils:

```
cd kms-cmake-utils
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make install
```

ok done, it installs a bunch of files in cmake module directory. then I tried to install kms-core:

```
cd kms-core
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

but cmake stops with following error

```
-- checking for module 'KurentoModuleCreator'
--   package 'KurentoModuleCreator' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/GenericFind.cmake:93 (message):
  Library KurentoModuleCreator not found
```

I tried to install kurento-module-creator:

```
cd kurento-module-creator
mvn install
```

it complies and installs some files in .m2 directory. I don't have any experience with maven to know if it is done correctly.

However it doesn't resolves the error with kms-core. apparently, cmake find_package command is not able to locate FindKurentoModuleCreator.cmake. I couldn't find the file in any Kurento's repos. can anybody please tell me if I am doing st wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, all kms related projects are ready to be build as debian packages.

Instead of using `cmake` and `make install` by hand, it will be easier for you to generate debian packages and install them.

The instructions to do generate are very simple:

```
export PROJECT_NAME=<project_name>
mkdir build_$PROJECT_NAME
cd build_$PROJECT_NAME
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/$PROJECT_NAME
cd $PROJECT_NAME
debuild -uc -us
```

Once debuild finishes successfully you will have some debian packages in `build_<project_name>` directory, you can just install them using:

```
sudo dpkg -i *deb
```

It is possible that debuild fails because dependencies are not met, in this case you may have to install them using apt-get or generate them if they are kurento dependencies.

Nevertheless, we have available all kurento packages (including some custom dependencies whose sources are also available on github), already compiled in kurento repository:

```
deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6
```

or in the dev channel that has all the master branches builds

```
deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty-dev kms6
```

Packages are for trusty release, because they are generated using this release which is the officially supported by kurento, but they can generally be installed on 15.04 too.