# No package 'KurentoModuleCreator' found

Tags: kurento

If KurentoHelpers is not found, then it is necessary to install
          kms-cmake-utils package from the kurento repository
-- Found KurentoModuleCreator_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for module 'KurentoModuleCreator'
--   No package 'KurentoModuleCreator' found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/GenericFind.cmake:93 (message):
  Library KurentoModuleCreator not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/CodeGenerator.cmake:5 (generic_find)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (include)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

when i build kms-core, cmake report this error. i have downloaded kurento-module-creator project, how can i install it on centos7, cmake version 3.5.0?

Comment: The official distribution supported is Ubuntu 14.04.  It will be easier if you try to compile the project and post any errors that you find. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403055/building-kurento-on-lubuntu-15-04?rq=1) answer as it might help you installing that, apart from the official documentation of course!

Comment: my work environment is centos，can i build kms on it? The company can not change work environment to ubuntu

Comment: sure ! some users have reported, in the mailing list, that they were able to.

Comment: But how can I solve this problem？

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install git maven
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-module-creator.git
cd ./kurento-module-creator
mvn install
cp ./target/kurento-module-creator-jar-with-dependencies.jar /usr/bin
cp ./scripts/kurento-module-creator /usr/bin
cp ./target/classes/FindKurentoModuleCreator.cmake /usr/local/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/
```

`/usr/local/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/` change you path to cmake modules.

PS: I'm sorry. My English very bad))

Answer (score 0):

Try to install kurento-module-creator project. This project is compiled with maven, just generate it with `mvn package` and then install the jar in the default binary directory (I don't know where they are installed in centos, probabli `/usr/bin`), along with the shell scripts.

Cmake files should go to default cmake directory (again I don't know where is it because I don't use centos, probably `/usr/share/cmake-<version>/Modules`)

However, as people is saying on the comments, the process can be hard an painfull. An other option is to use a ubuntu docker image to use kurento.

Comment: i`m runing these cmds in kurento-module-creator folder:mvn compile mvn install，generate two files in target folder：kurento-module-creator-4.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar，kurento-module-creator-jar-with-dependencies.jar and i install them to binary directory，cmake still report that error when i build kms-core.

Comment: You forget to install shell script and cmake file

Comment: i have installed FindKurentoModuleCreator.cmake and kurento-module-creator，are there any other files that need to be installed？

Comment: I think it's enough, but they have to be in the proper directories

Comment: There is no help when i copy kurento-module-creator                            kurento-module-creator-4.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar         kurento-module-creator-jar-with-dependencies.jar to /usr/bin/ and /usr/lib/ directories

Comment: Could you edit your question adding information of the steps you have done

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem with module compilation. I needed make some like this:

1. First set correct cmake path in CMakeList.txt

```
message ("If KurentoHelpers is not found, then it is necessary to install
          kms-cmake-utils package from the kurento repository")

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "/usr/local/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/") 

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake")
find_package(KurentoHelpers REQUIRED)
```

2. Copy FindKurentoModuleCreator to cmake-3.5/Modules

```
sudo cp FindKurentoModuleCreator.cmake /usr/local/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindKurentoModuleCreator.cmake
```

3. I've too change the CodeGenerator.cmake (Verify if need)

```
 sudo vi /usr/local/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CodeGenerator.cmake

From

set (KURENTO_MODULES_DIR /usr/share/kurento/modules CACHE PATH "Directory where kurento module descriptors can be found")
mark_as_advanced(KURENTO_MODULES_DIR)

To

set (KURENTO_MODULES_DIR /usr/local/share/kurento/modules CACHE PATH "Directory where kurento module descriptors can be found")
mark_as_advanced(KURENTO_MODULES_DIR)
```