# How to start kurento-media-server service on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kurento

I have followed the installation guide from https://github.com/Kurento/bugtracker/issues/140 
, Installation compeleted with success,But when i want to start kurento media sever by the following command :
sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
                                  I get the following error:
failed to start kurento-media-sever-6.0.sevice: unit kurento-media-server-6.0.service not found.

Comment: try reinstalling media server, also check if installation is completed then you will have a new user "kurento"

Answer (score 0):

I want to advice you to generate *.deb package and then install it using `dpkg`:

```
cd kurento-media-server/

# build a .deb package
`debuild -uc -us`

# install it using dpkg
sudo dpkg -i ../kurento-media-server-6.0_6.6.1_amd64.deb
```

also, check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410211/3380173 for more details about how to do it.

As for your problem, it seems that after `sudo make install` script executed, there are no `upstart`/`systemd` config generated, so you unable to launch it using `sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start`. You may find it living at `/usr/local/bin/kurento-media-server` and start it manually, but I don't think it's a good solution. You have to write you own `upstart`/`systemd` script manually in this case.